# Space anime movie from '90s with a spaceship that looks like a large sled with wings

Tags: story-identification, anime, space

I remember an anime from the 90s. It was on VHS back then.

- The spaceship looks like a large sled with wings.
- The commanding bridge was on top of it.
- The spaceship started on the water, maybe in the ocean.
- The crew could drive into the battle stations with ball-like structures to defend.

Does anyone know the name of this anime?

I drew the ship as best I could. (I'm not good at that, but I hope you can recognize the shape).

[image]
<sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

Comment: Almost sounds like "Battle of the Planets" / "G-Force" / "Science Ninja Team Gatchaman".  The Phoenix (main ship) was a blocky wedge, with the bridge section at the top aft.  The base (at least in Battle of the Planets) was an undersea facility.  Each crew member had a signature vehicle that would dock at various points of the Phoenix.  I'm less sure of the "ball-like structures to defend".  The Phoenix's main armament seemed to be racks upon racks of missiles that the non-leader male (kind of a hothead) would repeatedly stab a large red button to launch.

Comment: Thanks JRE for editing. Thanks CaptAlgorithm for answering.

Unfortunately, no. i think it was a different movie.
I drew the ship as best I could. (I'm not good at that, but I hope you can recognize the shape. 
Link here.
https://postimg.cc/RWGXzwPk

Comment: And idea what colour it was? Also, what's large? 100 meters, 1k, 10k?

Comment: There was a direct to video anime remake of gatchaman in the mid 1990's. its possible it could be that... see if this looks familiar... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kB-H_0230vA

Comment: Certain elements of this remind me of Martian Successor Nadesico.  90s, split hull, bridge on top, rising out of the ocean.  But the 'upturned' front and 'ball like structures' do not match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could this be the 1980 movie [*"Cyborg 009: Legend of the Super Galaxy"*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0188535/)? (Wikipedia refers to it as [*"Cyborg 009: Legend of the Super Vortex"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyborg_009#1980_anime_film))

Despite the popularity of the "Cyborg 009" manga, which spawned three different anime series in the years from 1968 to 2002 (the second of which was broadcast dubbed in many countries, and was a great success in Europe), this particular movie seems to be quite obscure, so much so that it's difficult to find a summary longer than a handful of lines.

Anyway, the whole movie can be easily found on YouTube, and from a quick glance it could be what you are looking for.

> - The spaceship looks like a large sled with wings.
> - The commanding bridge was on top of it.

Here is the ship inside some kind of dry dock: I would say if fits your description
[image]

> - The spaceship started on the water, maybe in the ocean.

Dr. Gilmore and the 9 cyborgs find the ship under the sea, and they make contact with the peaceful alien inside it (at about 00:12:00).
Later on (at about 00:36:00) the ship emerges from the sea and launch into space.
[image]

> - The crew could drive into the battle stations with ball-like structures to defend.

On the bridge, the crew member (the 9 cyborg and the alien they are helping) sit on round pods (for example at 00:40:50).
[image]

Later on (00:54:30) they are attacked by enemy ships, and some of the cyborgs use the moving pods to reach and man gun turrets.
[image]

Comment: I almost hesitated to upvote you, because you had 6502 points, and that's a nice number.  But then I figured if I didn't, someone else would, so I did it anyway. :D

Comment: that's it! 
also from my brother who had had these memories double checked. Thanks very much! a long search has a happy ending.
and I'm also happy that my memories weren't so wrong with the details :)
thanks also for the background information!

Answer (score 11):

I don't think this is it, but I'm posting to rule it out, or possibly you've conflated two different things . . .

Is it the S-1 from [*"Arthur Christmas"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Christmas)?

The S-1 flies in [at this point](https://youtu.be/vxcz1XIKUmo?t=54) in the trailer

[image]

Side View

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Space battleship Yamato has an "upturned nose" which could be mis-remembered as a sled-like look.

I'm unaware of any public domain images of the ship, but https://yamato.fandom.com/wiki/Yamato_(2199)?file=Yamato_2199_First_Liftoff.png makes it look a bit like your drawing in profile.

There are, as far as I know, no balls involved.

Answer (score 1):

I have two possible guesses (according to "The spaceship started on the water, maybe in the ocean.")

The best one could be [Robotech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotech_(TV_series)), aka [Macross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Dimension_Fortress_Macross).
The main base of the humans, the [SDF-1](https://robotech.fandom.com/wiki/SDF-1), was on a small island in the middle of the Pacific Ocean, then in order to escape the first attacks by the invading aliens it had to reach the space.
Even if it was better remembered because it could transform into a humanoid shape, its normal shape could somehow remember a sled (even if different from the one drawn by the OP).

The second guess is [Space Carrier Blue Noah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Carrier_Blue_Noah). It is a super-submarine that, in order to fight against an alien invasion, is later refitted with a space engine, so that it can fight in the space.
It also has a shape that could be somehow similar to a sled, when it is on the surface of the sea and opens itself (as you can see in the [opening](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axlD4nf-H8M) (Italian)).

Answer (score -2):

Going to say Nadesico.  Based on your description of the action, at least.
https://nadesico.fandom.com/wiki/ND-001_Nadesico

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to specify the ways in which this matches the anime described in the question, and any ways in which it doesn't. Specifying the year in which it was released would be helpful too.